# Can I join 2 tables the rename the join using `AS` in order to join with yet a third table?

Tags: mysql

Can I do something as below? The reason I need to do this is because table 3 has a different column name for ID.

```
select *
from (table1 join table2 using(ID)) as result 
join table3 
on result.ID = table3.different_ID
```

Currently I'm having a syntax error, but my query is rather complex so I'm not sure whether this is the problem or something else.

Comment: No, your derived table needs to be a SELECT. So change, `(table1 join table2 on(ID))` to something like (SELECT table1.* FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having you considered just using `on`?

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.id join 
     table3 
     on table1.ID = table3.different_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (ID)
) result
JOIN table3 ON result.ID = table3.different_ID;
```

EDIT: Updated to reflect OP's original intent and fit OP's needs considering query complexity

Comment: My table 1 is in fact the result of another `SELECT` statement. I thus cannot refer to it by name as in `SELECT table1.*, table2.*`. Is there a way to get around this? Can't I just do `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT table1.*, table2.*`?

Comment: @Anh There are a couple ways... 1. You could avoid the sub-query structure and do multiple joins on multiple tables. 2. You could create a view for table1. 3. Probably more, but these are the ones that come to mind. If I had to guess, I'd say your entire query could be strategically built with LEFT and INNER joins, avoiding sub-queries altogether

Comment: So what's the problem with `SELECT *` versus `SELECT table1.*, table2.*`?

Comment: @Anh Nothing, I put that in there so you could define the columns that you wanted to pull

Comment: So doesn't `SELECT *` get around the need to refer to `table1` by name then? I'm sure your suggestions are more optimal, but I'm just wondering whether my suggestion works at all.

Comment: @Anh Yes, it removes the need to refer to the table, as far as what columns you're selecting. I assume you have something you can copy/paste in place of `table1` in the FROM section